# Ubuntu Cloud-init User cant login

Tags: ubuntu, cloud-init

I have created an ISO to mount to a prepped Ubuntu template, so when it deploys and boots the first time, Cloud init adds some users and do a few commands. Everything seems to work fine as far as i can see. Users gets added to the passwd, created /home/ dirs and i can see their password in /etc/shadow where there password is not locked or something. (used both encrypted and not) However, If i go to the vmware webconsole, I cant login with any of the added users. Only the root and administrator (which i created while prepping the template) can login.

How can i fix this?

Comment: When you are logged on as root, can you `ssh localhost` and log on as one of the users? Also check if `/etc/nologin` exists. What errors are reported in `/var/log/auth.log`?

Comment: thanks for your trouble. The logs where just saying authentication failed. see my own answer for the possible reason.

Answer (score 1):

So I have figured it out. It works when the passwd in user-data is specifically sha-512 salt=4096 encrypted. Also set the shell: /bin/bash. But only the shell wasn't enough.

Comment: how do you go about applying SHA512 with that salt to your password?

Comment: mkpasswd --method=SHA-512 --rounds=4096